# Best place to call activity in-out animations

Tags: java, android, animation, android-activity

What is the best place to call fade-in and fade-out animations to animate during forward/backward transitions between activities. I tried the following but fade-out animation is not activated in the current activity when starting another activity:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
    findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).startAnimation(animation);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
    findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).startAnimation(animation);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: more like onPause onResume

Comment: @njzk2 It actually depends on what you're fading in and out. Also, if you ask me, it's not onPause and onResume, but onWindowFocusChanged. ;)

Comment: animation is visible when onStart, onPause and onResume are used. but it is not visible when used with onStop? is it because onStop is called after the activity is moved to background completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) method.

Call immediately after one of the flavors of `startActivity(Intent)` or `finish()` to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work"? You call this method and nothing happens or you can't use this method because of something?

Comment: Samsung devices and some others need option Settings -> Display -> Animation set to value "All animations".